# Terraform: Waiting for App Configuration Key read permission to be propagated

Tags: terraform, azure-rm, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to create an app configuration with two features but I get an error:

```
│
│   with module.appconfig.azurerm_app_configuration_feature.advanced,
│   on app_config\main.tf line 27, in resource "azurerm_app_configuration_feature" "keyname":│   27: resource "azurerm_app_configuration_feature" "keyname" {
│
│ waiting for App Configuration Key ".appconfig.featureflag/keyname" read permission to be propagated: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Error, Exists' (last state: 'Forbidden', timeout: 44m59.3893417s)   
╵
```

This is my code snippet:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "data" {
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "rg-sample-4"
  location = "eastus"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "app_configuration_role" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.test.id
  role_definition_name = "App Configuration Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.data.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "this" {
  name                       = "appconfig-94"
  resource_group_name        = "rg-sample-4"
  location                   = "eastus"
  sku                        = var.APP_CONFIGURATION_SKU
  local_auth_enabled         = var.APP_CONFIGURATION_LOCAL_AUTH_ENABLED #true
  public_network_access      = var.APP_CONFIGURATION_PUBLIC_NETWORK_ACCESS #"Enabled"
  purge_protection_enabled   = var.APP_CONFIGURATION_PURGE_PROTECTION_ENABLED #false
  soft_delete_retention_days = var.APP_CONFIGURATION_SOFT_DELETE_RETENTION_DAYS #1

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.app_configuration_role,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration_feature" "keyname" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.this.id
  description            = var.ADVANCED_FEATURE_DESCRIPTION
  name                   = var.ADVANCED_FEATURE_NAME
  label                  = var.ADVANCED_FEATURE_LABEL
  enabled                = var.ADVANCED_FEATURE_ENABLED
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration_feature" "keynametwo" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.this.id
  description            = var.EXTENSION_FEATURE_DESCRIPTION
  name                   = var.EXTENSION_FEATURE_NAME
  label                  = var.EXTENSION_FEATURE_LABEL
  enabled                = var.EXTENSION_FEATURE_ENABLED
}
```

```
 azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.52.0"
    }
```

I took this from: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15721#issuecomment-1103532799

And I also checked the documentation but anything doesnt work for me: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration_feature

Does anybody know the reason for that error and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "xx"
    storage_account_name = "remotestate"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

Use time_sleep to wait for the role to be created .

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "app_configuration_role" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "App Configuration Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

}

resource "time_sleep" "role_assignment_sleep" {
  create_duration = "60s"

  triggers = {
    role_assignment = azurerm_role_assignment.app_configuration_role.id
  }
}
```

Then add **`depends_on`**  >  **`time_sleep.role_assignment_sleep`** so that app configuration creattion waits for the role  creation and could read the keys

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "this" {
  name                       = "appconfig"
  resource_group_name        =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                        = <sku>
  local_auth_enabled         = true
  public_network_access      = "Enabled"
  purge_protection_enabled   = false
  soft_delete_retention_days = 1

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.app_configuration_role,
   time_sleep.role_assignment_sleep
  ]
}
```

Upon **`terraform plan`**

[image]

Upon **`terraform apply`**

[image]